# Read property from QML singleton with C++

Tags: c++, qt, properties, singleton, qml

Is it possible to access/read the properties of a QML singleton inside your C++ code?

For example if my QML singleton looks like this:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.5

QtObject {
  property int myProperty: 5
}
```

How can I access myProperty from C++ code. I need this as I do not want to have my "magic" numbers both in QML and C++ and it is only very rarely required in C++.

For normal QQuickItem's it was always easy. Just get access to the QuickItem (by dynamic creating it or with findChild()) and than call `quickItem->property("myProperty").toInt()`
But with the singleton I can't see how to get access to it.

Comment: Why does it matter if you have the singleton type declared in C++ or not? I'm not sure how you can do this, but it sounds like you're better off just declaring it in C++.

Comment: Accessing QML objects from C++ is pretty discouraged. I'd recommend to try the oposite: declare your singleton object in C++ properly and set it as a context property in your QQmlApplicationEngine. That way you'd be able to access it in a very straightforward way in both worlds.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!
The solution I finally implemented calculates the needed values in QML so I can directly access the property with the result from C++.
Changing the current architecture to use a C++ singleton was just to expensive as the QML singleton is already well established.

Comment: @TobiasSch.: Could you explain in more detail how you solved this? Where do you put the code that "calculates the needed values in QML" and "the property with the result", so that it is accessible from C++? BTW it's nice to post as a self-answer and not just as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not *directly*, one way to access a QML singleton is via a function in a non-singleton QML object, that you can access in the usual way:

**Constants.qml**

```
pragma Singleton

import QtQuick 2.5

QtObject {
    objectName: "Constants"
    property double phi: 1.6180339887498948482
}
```

**main.qml (e.g.)**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import "."

function getPhi()
{
    return Constants.phi;
}
```

**C++**

```
//...
// Create the engine and load QML
//...

QObject* rootObject = engine->rootObjects().constFirst();

QVariant phi;
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(rootObject, "getPhi", Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, phi));
qDebug() << phi.toFloat();
```

Don't forget you'll need a [qmldir](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html) file to access the singleton in QML:

**qmldir**

```
singleton Constants Constants.qml
```

Comment: Thank you for the late but very much appreciated answer. It confirms my believe that there is no easy or really convince way to do so.

Comment: @TobiasSch. seems pretty easy to me